# Value undefined when sending to firebase

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, variables, slider

Hello I have a slider on my webpage with a range from 1 to 10:

```
 <div class="slidecontainer">
                <p  style="font-size: large; font-weight: bold;"> Aantal sets: <span id="dynamicSet" ></span></p>
                <input type="range" min="1" max="10" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
 </div>
<button  onclick = "window.location.href = '#close'; collection();" href="#close" id="submitButton" class="tester2"  > Submit </button>
```

The amount of teh slider I try to save in setAmount variable.

```
var setAmount;
output.innerHTML = slider.value
    update=()=>{
        output.innerHTML = slider.value; 
        // Display the default slider value
        console.log(slider.value);
        setAmount = slider.value;
        console.log(setAmount);
    }

// Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
slider.addEventListener('input', update);
```

My console shows the value change as i move the slider. I try to save the amount in setAmount. But it returns undefined. the sldier is part of my form. and when the suer clicks submit i try to send it to my firebase DB. But it seems like before i even get that far I cant even save it properly. As when i save it in my Db it returns undefined.

```
function writeData(){
    firebase.database().ref("Exercise").set({
        setAm: setAmount, 
    });
}
function collection(){
    writeData();
}
```

what could be the cause of this?

EDIT: Made a codepen: https://codepen.io/zakaria250/pen/zYvvXjr

Comment: The code you shared doesn't show how/when you call `writeData`. Aside from that, if you `console.log(setAmount)` right before setting it to the database, what does it show?

Comment: Hi Frank, thank you for taking a look at my problem. Please see my edit.   If i just open the page ts is undefined. If i move the slider to a random value i can see in my console log the value.  Also maybe good to mention, the first chunk of Javascript code is not in a function im not sure if that has to do witha anything..?

Comment: If i save the value setAmount in another variable and console log that if shows undefined whether locally or in a function. its like it doesnt save the value at all.

Comment: I made a codepen demo hopefully you can help me out! https://codepen.io/zakaria250/pen/zYvvXjr

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to be 100% sure with only the code snippets you have shared but the cause of your problem is probably the fact that your form is submitted before the Firebase `set()` method is triggered.

As a matter of fact, you declare your button as follows:

```
<button onclick = "window.location.href = '#close'; collection();" href="#close" id="submitButton" class="tester2"  > Submit </button>
```

i.e. without any `type` attribute.

As detailed in the [W3 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-button-element) on button types, "the missing value default is the Submit Button state" and "if the `type` attribute is in the Submit Button state, **the element is specifically a submit button**".

So, if you add a `button` type to your button, as follows, it should solve your problem.

```
<button type="button" onclick = "window.location.href = '#close'; collection();" href="#close" id="submitButton" class="tester2">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you so muhc for your answer. Sadly however It did not solve my issue. I understand It is not easy given the code  i gave. Thats why i recreated my website in  codepen. you can demo it here:

https://codepen.io/zakaria250/pen/zYvvXjr

Thank you so much for your time. I hope you can help me solve this.