# how to add data on firebase form React Js

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

My user are added to authentication, but somehow it's not adding data to Realtime database and even file which was uploading before now they also not uploading to the storage.

**Rejister.jsx**

```
> import React, { useState } from 'react'
> import profile from "../assets/user.png"
> import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword, updateProfile } from "firebase/auth";
> import { ref, set } from "firebase/database";
> import { auth, storage , database  } from '../firebase';
> import { uploadBytesResumable, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage";
> 
> function Rejister() {
> 
> const [err, setErr] = useState()
> 4
> const handleSubmit = async(e) => {
> e.preventDefault()
> const displayName = e.target[0].value
> const email = e.target[1].value
> const password = e.target[2].value
> const file = e.target[3].files[0]
> 
> try {
> const res = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
> console.log(res)
> const storageRef = ref(storage, `${displayName}/${file.name}`)
> const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file)
> 
> uploadTask.on((err) => {
> setErr(true);
>       }, ()=> {
> getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref)
>         .then(async (downloadURL) => {
> await updateProfile(res.user, {
> displayName: displayName,
> photoURL: downloadURL,
>           })
> await set(ref(database, 'users'), {
> username: displayName,
> email: email,
> photoURL : downloadURL
>           });
> 
> console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
>         });
>       })
> catch (err) {
> setErr(true)
>     }
>   }
> 
> return (
>     <div className='formContainer'>
>         <div className='formWrapper'>
>             <span className='rejister-logo'>Talkies</span>
>             <span className='rejister-title'>Rejister</span>
>             <form className='rejistration-form' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
>                 <input type="text" placeholder='Your Name' />
>                 <input type="email" placeholder='Email'/>
>                 <input type="password" placeholder='Password'/>
>                 <input type="file" id='file' style={{display: 'none'}} />
>                 <label htmlFor="file" className='file-uploder'>
>                 <img src={profile} /> 
>                 <span>Add Profile Photo</span>
>                 </label>
>                 <button className='sign-up-btn'>Sign Up</button>
>                 {err && <span> Something Went Wrong.</span>}
>             </form>
>             <p className='rejistration-para'>Do you already have an account? Login </p>
>         </div>
>     </div>
>   )
> }
> 
> export default Rejister;
```

**Firebase_Config.js**

```
> import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
> import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
> import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
> import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database";
> import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";
> 
> 
> const firebaseConfig = {
> apiKey: "**************************",
> authDomain: "**********************",
> projectId: "***********",
> storageBucket: "********************",
> messagingSenderId: "*****************",
> appId: "*************************************",
> measurementId: "**********"
> };
> 
> export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
> export const auth = getAuth(app)
> export const storage = getStorage(app);
> export const database = getDatabase(app);
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61217982/3371862

Comment: @RenaudTarnec this is not the case in my code trigger is perfectly place and fine there is some other error which i am not able to get yet